# Class of multiple items

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have a class **Company**, and a class **Tax**. Depending on the country where the company is being created, I create multiple **Tax** Objects for this **Company**. For example, if the country is Norway, I need to create 4 tax objects by default.

Now to have this structure, I firstly created a class for each distinct Tax that I have. Those for example are two taxes that I have:

```
class TaxNorway11 extends Tax {

    public function __construct($companyID, $config = []) {
        $this->name = 'Tax 11.00%';
        $this->percentage = 11;
        $this->company = $companyID;
        parent::__construct($config); 
    }
}

class TaxNorway12 extends Tax {

    public function __construct($companyID, $config = []) {
        $this->name = 'Tax 12%';
        $this->percentage = 12;
        $this->company = $companyID;
        parent::__construct($config); 
    }
}
```

Then I created a TaxFactory that checks the $country and creates the Tax Objects accordingly:

```
class TaxFactory {

    public function build() {

        switch ($country) {
            case self::NORWAY_ID:
                $tax11 = new TaxNorway11($this->companyID);
                $tax15 = new TaxNorway15($this->companyID);
                $tax12 = new TaxNorway12($this->companyID);
                $this->taxes = array($tax11, $tax12, $tax15);
                break;

        }

        return $this->taxes;
    }
}
```

I have multiple countries though, and thus I will end up creating many classes, one for each Tax Object. My Question is, is there a way by which I can create a class made of a list, for example NorwayTaxes that will have all the taxes for Norway. This is specially since every time I create a company there I will have to use the full list, so it seems that its a better way to organize the code?

Comment: `$this->taxes[$country] = array($tax11, $tax12, $tax15);` ?

Comment: You might even find some suitable pattern in the Structural Design Patterns, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

Comment: I can think of following solution: - Tax class should contain only name and percentage - Company class should contain list of taxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you are breaking the [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) there. You have hard-coded configuration in your classes. Also, the company is **not** a part of. Taxes get applied to the income and/or revenue of the company.

Instead of making a one class per each country per each tax, you should create classes, that exhibit a common taxing behavior. For example, you create a class (which implements `Taxation` interface) for applying tax of a defined percentage, with specified "exempt amount". And then you will have another class with the same interface, that applies percent-based tax with fixed "max amount". That would mean, you only need two classes. You just initialize them with specific constructor parameters.

Also, this approach will let you keep a categorized list of taxes in your database and configure, which taxes get applied for a specific company in each country.